# How to subscribe to events on Linked IN page using the API

Tags: linkedin-api

We are trying to subscribe to the events happening on the company's page using the below API

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication%3Aurn%3Ali%3AdeveloperApplication%3A4640701,user%3Aurn%3Ali%3Auser%3Ammcro6uJzZ%2Centity%3Aurn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A26639300,eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)?oauth2_access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...

However we are getting the below error in response :

{
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"message": "Field Value validation failed in RESOURCE_KEY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/key/user]",
"status": 403
}

Unable to get through this.
documentation reference :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-social-action-notifications

Can some one help me here.

Comment: is the above issue resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

They didn't change the curl, you need to trade the "user:urn:li:user:{member ID}" to "user:urn:li:person:{member ID}"